# Python calendar heatmap html

Tags: python

I wanted to create a heatmap using the calendar module but I didn't find anything in the documentation. So I edited the calendar module to be able to do this and I want to share it, also the answer in this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63813409/python-calendar-add-custom-colors) gave me an idea of where to start.

Comment: This is not a question? It's generally bad practice to edit library code, but if you want to do so then it's best to make a pull request to the library on github.

Answer (score 0):

in the calenday.py file I made this changes:

- in the class HTMLCalendar(Calendar)

  ```
  def formatday(self, day, weekday,color):
      """
      Return a day as a table cell.
      """
      hexa= color.get(day)
      if day == 0:
          return '<td class="%s">&nbsp;</td>' % self.cssclass_noday
      else:
          return '<td class="%s"style="background-color:%s">%d</td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], hexa,day)


  def formatweek(self, theweek,color):
      """
      Return a complete week as a table row.
      """

      s = ''.join(self.formatday(d,wd,color) for (d, wd) in theweek)
      return '<tr>%s</tr>' % s


  def formatmonth(self, theyear, themonth,color, withyear=True):
      """
      Return a formatted month as a table.
      """
      v = []
      a = v.append
      a('<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="%s">' % (
          self.cssclass_month))
      a(self.formatmonthname(theyear, themonth, withyear=withyear))
      a(self.formatweekheader())
      for week in self.monthdays2calendar(theyear, themonth):
          a(self.formatweek(week,color))
      a('</table>')
      return ''.join(v)
  ```

and then I use this to create the calendar heatmap, I took the f2hex function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206300/assign-color-to-value):

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[9195.6,3497.4,5802,3331.9,5591.8,2618.8,10198.2,261.8]]
dff = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'], dtype = float) 

vmin = dff.sum().min()
vmax = dff.sum().max()

norm = colors.Normalize(vmin,vmax)
f2rgb = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.get_cmap('GnBu'))


def f2hex(f2rgb, f):
    rgb = f2rgb.to_rgba(f)[:3]
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % tuple([int(255*fc) for fc in rgb])



colors_dict = {0:'#FFFFFF'}
for i in dff.columns:
    colors_dict[int(i)] = f2hex(f2rgb,int(dff[i]))
    
c = calendar.HTMLCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY)
c.formatmonth(2020,9,colors_dict)
```

So the final output is an HTML code the generates the following table:

[image]

Hope this can be useful.